# EM Induction from Diffusing Ionic Wave Front

Tags: electrochemistry, redox, molecular-dynamics

I am studying the [Belousov-Zhabotinsky Reaction-Diffusion system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belousov%E2%80%93Zhabotinsky_reaction) in ~1mm wide 1-dimensional channels. In my research we are activating the reduced phase with a silver wire and studying the propagation of the oxidized wavefront through space. I am using the standard malonic acid, sodium bromate, sulfuric acid, and ferroin recipe. If you are interested in the mechanism [here it is](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Oregonator).

The light blue wavefront is an "activator" species which is negatively charged. My question is whether a diffusing ionic wavefront is known to induce an electromagnetic field, and how one would calculate its order given the molarity or charge of the wavefront. [Magnetic fields are already known to affect BZ waves](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/bem.20420), but my question is whether BZ waves can themselves produce magnetic fields.

Please let me know how I could improve this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly, it *would* produce a detectable EM effect.
Likely, an electrostatic effect could be detected with insulated probes immersed in the mix and a [high-impedance (100 MΩ or higher) voltmeter](https://sound-au.com/project212.htm). However, such a setup would be slow to respond, perhaps on the order of seconds, due to low capacitively-coupled current, high impedance, and inevitable circuit capacitance. Don't expect to detect fast transients.

However, detecting external electro*magnetic* effects might be quite difficult because of the very low amplitude and frequency. You might need to use a [superconducting quantum interference device (SQUID)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQUID). "Most fundamental measurements in biomagnetism, even of extremely small signals, have been made using RF SQUIDS." While that would be *way cool*, it might be a bit out of budget in most labs. Perhaps there's a physiology lab nearby that might give time on their apparatus?